# Problem comparing an input date to the current date

Tags: javascript, html, validation, date, datetime

I'm trying to create a web page that allows a user to input some information about an airplane flight. I want to validate the dates and times of the departure/arrival of the flight, to make sure the arrival is after the departure and the departure is after the current date, etc. 
I have the departure vs arrival comparisons working, but the departure and current date comparison isn't doing anything.

For a different page I have, adding Date.parse() around the user input date worked (var depDate = Date.parse(document.forms["newFlight"]["departure_date"].value;)) but here, that just makes none of the date comparisons work and doesn't even fix the current date comparison problem.

```
<head>
<script>
function validateDatePrice() {
  var basePrice = document.forms["newFlight"]["base_price"].value;
  var depTime = document.forms["newFlight"]["departure_time"].value;
  var arrTime = document.forms["newFlight"]["arrival_time"].value;
  var depDate = document.forms["newFlight"]["departure_date"].value;
  var arrDate = document.forms["newFlight"]["arrival_date"].value;
  var currDate = new Date(); 

  if (isNaN(basePrice)) {
    alert("Please enter a numerical value for base price.");
    return false;
  }
  if (currDate <= depDate) {
    alert("The departure date must be after the current date.");
    return false;
  }
  if (depDate > arrDate) {
    alert("Arrival date must be the same as or after the departure date.");
    return false;
  }
  if (depDate == arrDate && depTime >= arrTime) {
    alert("Arrival time must be later than departure time, if your flight takes off and lands on the same day.");
    return false;
  }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form name = "newFlight" action="/airlineStaff/addFlightAuth" onsubmit="return validateDatePrice()" method="POST">
    Departure Date: <input type="date" name = "departure_date" placeholder="departure date" required/> </br>
    Departure Time: <input type="time" name = "departure_time" placeholder="departure time" required/> </br>

    Arrival Date: <input type="date" name = "arrival_date" placeholder="arrival date" required/> </br>
    Arrival Time: <input type="time" name = "arrival_time" placeholder="arrival time" required/> </br>

    $ <input type="text" name = "base_price" placeholder="base price" required/> </br>

    <input type="submit" value = "Submit"/>
    <input type="reset">
    {% if error %}
        <p class="error"><strong>Error:</strong> {{error}}</p>
    {% endif %}
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The if statement for (currDate <= depDate) never results in false, the alert message is never shown. 
I want the alert message to pop up, and the user to be forced to fix the departure date, if the departure date is equal to or before the current date.

Comment: Hello, to me it seems that you are comparing Date to string. Try to compare it as currDate <= new Date(depDate)

Comment: it worked, thank-you so much!!